# What are the differences between instantiating a class and using its methods and making methods static and using them without instantiating the class

Tags: c#, static-methods

I know this is a very basic question. Also second part does not fit well in OO world. However when I googled about the answers, I got many results and some of them are conflicting so thought of clearing all things. Also I want to know the difference in terms of the memory allocation for the methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't care if something is OO, you should care if its appropriate in a certain situation.

Comment: Here is the best explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Comment: @CodesInChaos: yeah I agree.. I asked the question in general context so added that line..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we use classes in OO programming is so that we can *encapsulate state*.  A static method will (at best) only maintain a single state.  An instantiated object can maintain a state that is unique to that instance, and separate instances have no affect on eachother (unless explicitly implemented).

For example, imagine a simple class that maintains a count of how many times a method was called, and exposes that count through a property.  Using only static members, you can only ever have one count.  Using instance members, you can create multiple objects and each will maintain its own distinct count.

If a member doesn't have any state at all (that is, a method uses no variables that aren't declared within or passed as parameters to that method) then making it static is a good idea.

Comment: When we do methods as static, would it hold any overheads in memory perspective?

Comment: Static methods have no extra overhead compared to instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use. If you need a couple of methods doing different things **or** if you do not have any non-static members, you should use a static class.

If your methods depend on each other's processed data and you have the need to create variables and properties, you should stick to non-static classes as the user can initialize more than one instance at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create static methods if you want your methods to perform some utility tasks on its own without having to maintain any context.

However classes that are to be instantiated maintains some context in terms of member variables and member objects. The functions use those context to perform some operation for you.

Answer (score 0):

let say you want to use some function in different places in the project let say it calculate something so it doesn't have any vars so you don't need it after it's done it perpase you declare it static

sorry about my poor English